# Awk to find lines within date range in a file with custom date format

Tags: linux, bash, date, awk

I'm trying to find all lines between a date range in a file. However dates are formatted in a non standard way. Is there a way for awk to read these? The log file is formatted like so:

```
Jan  5 11:34:00 log messages here
Jan 13 16:21:00 log messages here
Feb  1 01:14:00 log messages here
Feb 10 16:32:00 more messages
Mar  7 16:32:00 more messages
Apr 21 16:32:00 more messages
```

For example if I want to pull all lines between January 1st and Feb 10th:
I've tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} ($0>=from&&$0<=to)' from="Jan  1 00:00:00" to="Feb 10 23:59:59"
```

It's a system that only has access to awk so I am kind of limited. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Thanks alot for the answers so far! They've worked great and have helped my understanding of AWK.  However I did forget to mention I need to be able to include the time as well.

For example finding lines in the range including and between:

`Jan  1 12:34:00`

and

`Feb 20 14:23:01`

EDIT2: Based on the answer provided by @Cyrus, I decided to use this to parse through times as well:

`awk -v start="0101 10:23:22" -v stop="0210 14:21:02" \
    'BEGIN{m["Jan"]="01"; m["Feb"]="02"; m["Mar"]="03"; m["Apr"]="04"}
    {original = $0; $1 = m[$1]; $2 = sprintf("%.2d", $2)}
    $1$2$3 >= start && $1$2$3 <= stop {print original}' file`

Comment: If you normalize month names to numbers, you can do a straight lexicographic comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk. `0101` is January 1st and `0210` February 10th.

```
awk -v start="0101" -v stop="0210" \
    'BEGIN{m["Jan"]="01"; m["Feb"]="02"; m["Mar"]="03"; m["Apr"]="04"}
    {original = $0; $1 = m[$1]; $2 = sprintf("%.2d", $2)}
    $1$2 >= start && $1$2 <= stop {print original}' file
```

Output:

```
Jan  5 11:34:00 log messages here
Jan 13 16:21:00 log messages here
Feb  1 01:14:00 log messages here
Feb 10 16:32:00 more messages
```

Comment: Modified this to use times as well:  `awk -v start="0101 10:24:23" -v stop="0210 15:23:22" \
    'BEGIN{m["Jan"]="01"; m["Feb"]="02"; m["Mar"]="03"; m["Apr"]="04"}
    {original = $0; $1 = m[$1]; $2 = sprintf("%.2d", $2)}
    $1$2$3 >= start && $1$2$3 <= stop {print original}' file`

Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$1)+2)/3
    date  = sprintf("%02d%02d", mthNr, $2)
}
(date >= from) && (date <= to)

$ awk -v from='0101' -v to='0210' -f tst.awk file
Jan  5 11:34:00 log messages here
Jan 13 16:21:00 log messages here
Feb  1 01:14:00 log messages here
Feb 10 16:32:00 more messages
```

Massage to suit...

Comment: This works pretty good too but I forgot to mention I need to be able to specify time ranges as well

Comment: Is it how to add times not obvious and trivial?

Comment: well I did try this method which didnt work.
`{
    mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$1)+2)/3
    date  = sprintf("%02d%02d %s", mthNr, $2,$3)
}
(date >= from) && (date <= to)

$ awk -v from='0101 10:23:00' -v to='0210 16:23:22' -f tst.awk file`

I keep getting syntax errors on the 1st colon of the 'to' variable.

Im sorry, this isnt obvious to me as I am new to awk and have spent quite a bit of time on this already.

Comment: Wish you'd copy/pasted the exact syntax error as what you wrote is correct best I can tell from the comment so I can't imagine what the syntax error could be about.

Comment: Hang on - you're not including the `$` at the start of the line `$ awk ...` are you? That `$` is just my prompt.